# Android show progress dialog while waiting for location

Tags: android, android-location

I'm developing location based app using this example: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-gps-location-manager-tutorial/

But when I turn on phone, the location isn't available right on that moment. So I would like to show progress dialog while waiting for the location. Wanna do this in the background using AsyncTask.

Can you give any ideas how and where to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need of AsyncTask because Location service already running in different process, Just implement the `LocationListener` and register it on resume method, and in onCreateActivity check if location is null, the show the `ProgressDialog`, and in `onLocationChanged()` set the location and close the `ProgressDialog`

Answer (score 2):

Place your ProgressDialog in onPreExecute, sample code below:

```
private ProgressDialog progressdialog;

@Override
protected void onPreExecute(){ 
   super.onPreExecute();
        progressdialog = new ProgressDialog(yourContext);
        progressdialog.setMessage("Loading...");
        progressdialog.show();    
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(){
   super.onPostExecute();
        progressdialog.dismiss();
}
```

Comment: Where do I put this? In my MainActivity? Because I want to show this untill I get my location! When I get the latitude and longitude I want to disable the dialog

Answer (score 2):

Implement locationListner interface and start your wait dialog override onlocation change method and there just cancel the dialog, all the best.

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener{

```
ProgressDialog dialog;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //-------------------- Start your GPS Reading ------------------ //
    dialog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    dialog.setMessage("Please wait!");
    dialog.show();

}
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location arg0) {
    dialog.dismiss();
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
```